# Can we use app.get() with any path in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

I want that

```
app.get('/a/path/from/browser', (req,res)=>{
//some code
})
```

becomes

```
app.get((req,res)=>{
//some code
})
```

I mean that I want that app.get() can response to any url instead of only a specific one.
I really want to keep app.get().

PS : Before the code I showed before, there is:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
```

Comment: You can use `*` to handle any route -> `app.get('*', (req,res)=>{`

Comment: Thank you @Molda